# In the Linux network system, do interfaces exist outside layers and protocols?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

I understand how a bridge is a layer 2 concept in that it forwards layer 2 packets such as ethernet fragments between other devices. But on my Linux system, docker0, which is a bridge, also has an IP address associated with it.

So that makes me wonder: does a network interface in Linux ***technically*** exist within a layer or protocol, or do Linux network interfaces exist in a kind of global space outside layers and protocols, and the layers/protocols just hang their addressing information on the interface data structure?

A tun interface might also be an example of a "layer 3 interface" since it only deals with IP datagrams and not ethernet fragments. Is "layer 3 interface" technically a thing, or is it just an "interface" that happens not to have any layer 2 info associated with it?

Comment: AFAIK any interface can *receive* a packet for any of a host's IP addresses.  Depending on configuration the kernel will even announce it's ip addresses via ARP on the "wrong" interface: https://serverfault.com/questions/834512/why-does-linux-answer-to-arp-on-incorrect-interfaces I believe (outbound) routing is bound to specific interfaces though.